# Stress mark of утро

Tags: ударение

The stress of the word утро seems to be irregular, since it depends on the absence or presence of a preposition.

According to some sources:

1. the stress is always **у́тр-** *without* a preposition.
2. the stress is always **утр-́** *after* a preposition.

However, it's again **утр-́** not necessarily after a preposition. Examples:

3. A dictionary of mine cites "в семь часов **утра́**"
4. Some books cite **утро́м** (or at least **рано утро́м**) to mean "in the morning".

So, what is the correct stress in each context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Almost true. Without a preposition stress is almost always on the first syllable

> рано ýтром
>   каждое ýтро

Except the word **утра́** with preposition **к**, **в**, **до** etc in the following phrases:

```
[preposition] [time] утра́
```

> к 8 часам утра́
>   в 7 часов утра́
>   до 6 часов утра́

---

2. Wrong. Not always.
   Examples:

> для [раннего] ýтра
>   в [столь раннее] ýтро

---

3. Correct. See the 1st item.

---

4. Wrong. The correct stress is on the first syllable:

> рано ýтром

---

Bonus pack.
There are also adverbs constructed from preposition and the word **утро**. They should be memorized.

> поутрý
>   наýтро

Answer (score 3):

1.the stress is always у́тр- without a preposition.--Correct. .

2.the stress is always утр-́ after a preposition.--No, not always.

> об у'тре, для такого у'тра, в это у'тро.

3.A dictionary of mine cites "в семь часов утра́"--Correct, an expression, should be memorized.

4 Some books cite утро́м (or at least рано утро́м) to mean "in the morning"No, this isn't correct. It should be "у'тром",the same "рано у'тром."